# Create a convention for ids using dapper

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-extensions, dommel

I'd like to create a convention to set the column that are named as "Id" to be primary key, I've been looking at the documentacion and so far I've foud ony to do it manually class by class like:
with dommel:

```
public class ProductMap : DommelEntityMap<TEntity>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        Map(p => p.Id).IsKey();
    }
}
```

I'd like something more like:

```
    public ConventionMap()
    {
        Properties<int>().Where(p=>p.Name.ToLower()=="id").isKey();
    }
```

it could be dommel or dapper extensions or any other, I just this implementation to be fluent.

any advice?
thanks!

Comment: Where do you need this for? Dapper itself has no knowledge about column names, table names and primary keys. Are you using DapperExtensions or Dommel?

Comment: either way I can move from one to another, I'm trying now with DapperExtensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dommel](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dommel) allows you to create a custom `IKeyPropertyResolver`.

Your implementation would look like:

```
public class CustomKeyPropertyResolver : DommelMapper.IKeyPropertyResolver
{
    public PropertyInfo ResolveKeyProperty(Type type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties().Single(p => p.Name.ToLower() == "id");
    }
}
```

Which should be registered at application start-up using this line of code:

```
DommelMapper.SetKeyPropertyResolver(new CustomKeyPropertyResolver());
```

You don't need Dapper.FluentMap (or Dapper.FluentMap.Dommel) for this. Also see: [the documentation](https://github.com/henkmollema/Dommel#ikeypropertyresolver).